# .NET GRPC communication is extremely slow, what I do wrong?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c++

This is my .NET controller:

```
// Change here - so it won't load every run - now we on ~200 RPS
private static readonly GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://10.0.0.10:50051");

private static readonly GreeterClient clinet = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

public RegularSungleThreadedController()
{
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var reply = await clinet.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
    return Ok(reply);
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class JustRespondController : ControllerBase
{

    public JustRespondController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok("No-Grpc");
    }
}
```

The .net core runs in a docker, this is how it's built:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestGrpcServerSpeed/TestGrpcServerSpeed.csproj", "TestGrpcServerSpeed/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestGrpcServerSpeed/TestGrpcServerSpeed.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestGrpcServerSpeed"
RUN dotnet build "TestGrpcServerSpeed.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestGrpcServerSpeed.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestGrpcServerSpeed.dll"]
```

This gRPC c++ server is a server from the gRPC example - no change made.
When I test `JustRespond` in my machine using `Locust` I get ~900RPS (which is slow compared to the advertise .NET 7 core performance) when I test `RegularSungleThreaded` I get ~200RPS (which is really slow).

There is plenty of available CPU and RAM during the tests.
What do I do wrong? maybe something in .NET should be set as a multi-threaded/process and I didn't set it? the gRPC performance should be sky-rock (they advertise 30kRPS)...

[The Locust res (~200RPS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY3Qn.png)

------- How to reproduce this -------

.net part:

1. Create a simple .net 7 in docker using the vs wizard, and copy paste the above logic in the controllers.
2. Install the latest Nuget needed to run gRPC client in .net (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
3. Use the simple Greeter proto from the gRPC open source (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.57.0/examples/protos/helloworld.proto)

The C++ gRpc part:

1. Create an Ubuntu docker
2. It install and runs as per the instructions here (https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/)
3. You can run any of the server versions there

Tested on Intel Xeon E-2386G, 32 GB Ram and reached ~700 RPS (without gRpc we reach ~2100RPS, it's looks like .net not using all available cores in the system for some reason - in pick it was ~15% of total CPU cores)

Comment: Did you use *Debug mode* or *Release mode* when building both the .NET GRPC client code & the C++ GRPC Server code? Performance tests should never be done using Debug mode. Other things that matter: what else is running on your machine, how much memory does it have, what CPU does it have, which OS is running, etc. It sounds like you are using a Dev PC and not a dedicated server. And also: "Creating a channel can be an expensive operation. Reusing a channel for gRPC calls provides performance benefits." but you create it for every controller instance.

Comment: This example isn't a good benchmark. Controller instances are created per request, which means this code creates a new gRPC connection for every incoming request. That's definitely *not* how gRPC is supposed to work.

Comment: Worse, the code doesn't dispose the channels which means it attempts to open 900 concurrent channels per second, that will only close when the GC runs.

Comment: As for `which is slow compared to the advertise .net 7 core performance` on what machine? Using what code, and how do you calculate the rate? What else is running on the same machine? When you run the test *and* server code on the same machine, both are competing for the same CPU and RAM. The test ends up interfering with the server. If the machine is slow, both will be slow.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I fix the bug of recreating a gRPC connect, now we at ~200 RPS still extremely slow.

Comment: @PeterB this is run on a docker so, it on Release

Comment: If you make calls against the same server instance, the garbage collection of the 900 orphaned channels will affect subsequent runs, so order matters. Even if you restart the server, application *startup* and *warmup* times will affect results. You need to wait a bit before you start counting. Benchmark libraries like `BenchmarkDotNet` account for this by having a warmup and cooldown period and keep running long enough to collect statistically significant results. You still need a way to restart the server between runs

Comment: @Meir docker means it's still running on the same machine as the test. And that isn't even your real question. This isn't a gRPC proxy.

Comment: @Meir `on a docker so, it on Release` not really.  Docker doesn't care whether the binary was built using the Debug or Release configuration. If the *Dockerfile* targeted Release, then yes, the build will be a Release build.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my grpc is a  local cache server (run on the same machine), This is kind of how it is in my prod as well, We check to see if there is a cached result in the grpc, and if we have we return it, if not, we do the job, and set the res in the grpc cache

Comment: gRPC is a protocol, not a database, cache or service. Essentially, you're trying to emulate Redis. Why not use Redis? As for the results you mentioned, up to this point they're measuring bugs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we have an internal cpp cache library (like Redis, with tweaks) that is written in C++, my service is.net, so I use gRPC to communicate between the languages.  The measurement I added is the updated ones (After the bug of the channel was fixed)

Comment: `This is kind of how it is in my prod as well,` and that skews results. If you want to compare benchmark results, you'll have to use similar setups. Right now, you're trying to compare the 0-60 performance of two cars, where one is loaded with 500Kg of test equipment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Currently I just want to understand why with gRPC in my testing environment I get ~200RPS and without the gRPC I get ~900RPS, this is a significant change that is not expected (the grpc returns just "hello world"), I get 22% of the possible performance on my test machine when I query `RegularSungleThreadedController` compared to `JustRespondController ` (and I have plenty of `CPU` available in my test machine (same as RAM) during the tests

Comment: Actually, you proved that gRPC is fast. `JustRespondController` returns a serialized compile-time constant. `RegularSungleThreadedController` isn't just returning Hello. It's making a *cross-process call* to another process, serializes a HelloRequest object into protobuf, wait for the server to respond, gets the response, deserializes it and only then sends a `Hello` back. All that for just 4.5x over the time for a no-op

Comment: Way back when ServiceStack claimed to be many times faster than ASP.NET Web API. Turns out, they used different clients for the tests, one using their own serializer, and one the obsolete JavascriptSerializer class instead of eg JSON.NET to generate the JSON they sent to the APIs. Using the *same* serializer showed that ServiceStack was *slower* than Web API.

Comment: _"Currently I just want to understand why with gRPC in my testing environment I get ~200RPS and without the gRPC I get ~900RPS"_ - sounds pretty fine for extra network call performed, TBH. You should compare `RegularSungleThreadedController` with another  one which will perform regular HTTP call with the same result.  _" this is run on a docker"_ - usually docker/k8s limits resources available to the container AFAIK.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I switch the use of grpc with regular HTTP server, I go from ~200RPS to ~300RPS

Comment: @GuruStron I let the docker use all the CPU and all the RAM (no limitation), with regular HTTP I go from ~200RPS to 300RPS

Comment: @Meir what is returned by `SayHelloAsync` (I would not be surprised by GRPC having worse perfromance when returning a single string compared to HTTP, i.e. when no actual serialization is happening)? What is returned by HTTP server? What is the location of HTTP server compared to the GRPC one? Can you please provide a full [mre] (including the both GRPC and HTTP servers)? _"I let the docker use all the CPU and all the RAM "_ - it still does not say much. Also do you generate load on the same machine as the docker with tested container is started?

Comment: Note that numbers which are advertised are achieved on pretty hefty hardware. [techempower](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r21&test=plaintext&hw=ph) uses  Dell R440 Xeon Gold + 10 GbE and [LesnyRumcajs grpc_bench/](https://github.com/LesnyRumcajs/grpc_bench/wiki/2022-04-23-bench-results)  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz, 32G RAM (both bare metal I assume). Plus the grpc bench measures .NET GRPC server, you are measuring something else.

Comment: @GuruStron by Grpc simple "Hello" string, by HTTP server a json with the system status (~400 bytes), both grpc and the HTTP server sit on the same server (each on a different docker), I do generate load on the same machine (the test is a compare of tests on the same machine with grpc, HTTP and none, and I compare their results) . I measure cpp grps server which should be faster then the c# versoin